# mysql select a row from table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

im trying to run this query to select the row "totaladclicks" row from the "statistics" table:

```
$sql = 'SELECT totaladclicks FROM statistics';
```

But i'm getting this:

SQL Error: Unknown column 'totaladclicks' in 'field list'

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post your table schema here? It seems that `statistics` table doesn't have `totaladclicks` column defined.

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  It seems really clear.

Comment: Error is explicit. What are you doing with this statement?

Comment: This is the statistics table.

https://image.ibb.co/bLOpsx/Immagine.jpg

@Gordon i know it's really clear but i can't understand since the totaladclicks row exists. Salmon: I'm trying to show in a table the value of totaladclicks. Ex: Total Ad Clicks: 20 - Already have everything, just can't get this query work.

Comment: Your statement is not valid sql so what else do you have in the mix , php perhaps?

Comment: What? I just need to fix this query. Everything except this works perfectly.

Comment: @Simone . . . You are probably connected to the wrong database or the wrong database server.

Comment: @Gordon: No it's impossible since i have another query in that page and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `totaladclicks` FROM statistics';
```

or:

```
$sql = "SELECT `totaladclicks` FROM statistics";
```

Backticks (upper comma, prime) should be used for system names, as well as column name to differentiate, as opposed to regular ticks (or apostrophes)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: backticks (upper comma, prime) should be used for system names, as well as column name to differentiate, as opposed to regular ticks (or apostrophes).

Comment: It will be better to edit your answer post instead of providing details in comments.